# How to disable Miscellaneous Scripts section from magento

Tags: javascript, security, magento, scripting

i m using magento 1.9.0.1 and there is a section in

```
admin area >> system >> Configuration >> General > Design > Miscellaneous Scripts
```

is there any way i can disable this area so no one can add any script to it, not sure but i tried changed

FTP Login
Cpanel Login
Database Login
Admin Login

And all possible areas and scanned the site as well and found no malware but still, someone adds the following script into

```
Miscellaneous Scripts
```

Of my website. here is the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getValue()
{
document.getElementById("headlineatas").style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
<div id="headlineatas">
<div id="topbar">
</div>
<div id="adsground">
<p align="left"><h3></h3></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div#b_icon1').hide();
$('div#b_icon2').hide();
$('div#b_icon3').hide();
$("div#h_icon1").mouseover(function() {
$('div#h_icon1').hide();
$('div#b_icon1').show();
});
$("div#h_icon2").mouseover(function() {
$('div#h_icon2').hide();
$('div#b_icon2').show();
});
$("div#h_icon3").mouseover(function() {
$('div#h_icon3').hide();
$('div#b_icon3').show();
});
$('#bannerfloat03').html('');
});
});
</script>
<div style="left: 400px; top: 300px; width: 338px; height: 280px; position: absolute" id="bannerfloatADS">
<script type="text/javascript">
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-8327339447162748";
google_ad_slot = "4629045516";
google_ad_width = 336;
google_ad_height = 280;
</script>
<!-- opoi -->
<script type="text/javascript"
src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
<div style="left: 260px; top: 11px; width: 110px; height: 0px; position:     absolute" id="h_icon2"><img alt="" src="http://www.icone-png.com/png/22/21536.png" /></div>
```

It ads google ads on my homepage script as popup, i do remove it from admin but it came back again and again after few hours of removal. Any suggestion on it to stop ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering like limit access to someone, try by adding a new role, and user assigned to those roles.
System->Permission->Roles
System->Permission->Users

I strongly would suggest apply all the patches available in order to keep your store secure. If you still are in the 1.9.0.1 version, you are missing a lot of security patches.

Comment: no this is not my mean, i mean i want to disable Miscellaneous Scripts field from admin area in total, either from code or from database but not sure where to and how to ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I would recommend to apply patches. For this specific issue. Somebody had brute forced your site and have access to your site admin and password. try to change the password to a difficult one and delete the misc script. If it worked. try to change all credentials for the site